# How to make Dropbox API Call using BrightScript?

Tags: dropbox-api, roku, brightscript

I am tryng to integrate dropbox in my Roku channel, I have created a Dropbox API App in Dropbox App Console. I am able to use curl to make the request:

```
$curl https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/ -H "Authorization:Bearer OAUTH_TOKEN"
```

With Brightscript I am using the following code,

```
req=CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")       
req.SetURL("https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/")
req.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer OAUTH_TOKEN")

req.AddHeader("app_key","APP_KEY")
req.AddHeader("app_secret","APP_SECRET")

req.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*")
req.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch")
req.GetToString()
```

Can anybody point me where I am doing wrong or am missing something? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting an error of some sort? BTW, the "app_key" and "app_secret" headers you're adding are not a real thing... they should be safe (ignored), but they don't do anything.

Comment: I tried without the app_key and app_secret too. There is no error, The response is invalid.

Comment: When you say "the response is invalid", what do you mean? You're not getting the response you're expecting? What response *are* you getting?

Comment: When I print the response, it prints invalid

Comment: That doesn't seem like useful output, so it's hard to guess what it means (unless someone with Roku experience can interpret). You might want to test with a tool like RequestBin (http://requestb.in/) to see what (if any) HTTP request is actually getting sent.

Comment: try dropping this line: req.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch") and see if that helps, pretty sure we only support gzip via roURLTransfer

Comment: what sucks is that `req.GetToString()` will never return the response codes. Most apps should use async networking anyway. But this makes problems like this one hard to debug.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are not properly initializing SSL for your roURLTransfer object:

```
req=CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")       
req.SetURL("https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/")


'****init https******
req.SetCertificatesFile("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt")
req.InitClientCertificates()
'****init complete****

req.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer OAUTH_TOKEN")

req.AddHeader("app_key","APP_KEY")
req.AddHeader("app_secret","APP_SECRET")

req.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*")
req.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch")
req.GetToString()
```